# Plotar série temporal horária em escala definida

Tags: r, datetime, time, plot, séries-temporais

Tenho um registro em série temporal horária, e estou com dificuldades para plotar em escala apropriada. Veja este exemplo:

```
#Gerar sinal v1     
v1=sin(seq(from=0, to=3*2*pi, length=11060))

#Gerar sinal v2
v2=sin(seq(from=0, to=5*2*pi, length=11060))

#Gerar série temporal horária entre 06-maio-2016 15h:00min e 10-ago-2017 10h:00min
time_series_total <- seq(from = as.POSIXct("2016-05-06 15:00"),
                         to = as.POSIXct("2017-08-10 10:00"), by = "hour")
```

Então, quando ploto:

```
plot(x = time_series_total, y = v1, type = 'l', col = "red", xlab = "tempo")
    lines(x = time_series_total, y = v2, col = 'blue')
    legend("topright", legend=c("v1", "v2"),
           col=c("red", "blue"), lty=1:1, cex = 1.25, box.lty=0,inset = 0.005)
```

... A escala das abcissas não fica legal

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]:

O que eu gostaria é de apresentar a escala dos eixos com as informações de mês e ano.
Qual a sugestão?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
plot(time_series_total, v1, type = 'l', col = "red", xlab = "tempo", xaxt = "n")
lines(x = time_series_total, y = v2, col = 'blue')
legend("topright", legend=c("v1", "v2"), col=c("red", "blue"), lty=1:1, cex = 1.25, box.lty=0,inset = 0.005)

r <- as.POSIXct(round(range(time_series_total), "days"))
axis.POSIXct(1, at = seq(r[1], r[2], by = "month"), format = "%Y-%m")
```

Comment: Legal, Willian! Conforme relatei, inseri um for para gerar os vários gráficos na mesma janela, e por isso editei teu código. Permaneço com uma dúvida, como automatizar o range do ylim. Você sabe?

Comment: @RafaelPedrollodePaes, como sugerido pelo Marcus Nunes, não é recomendando que você edite a questão de uma forma que mudará completamente o sentido da questão e, portanto, das respostas. Por isso, deixo minha resposta como original e sugiro que você desfaça sua edição e crie uma nova pergunta.

Comment: Ok, apesar de não ser o que eu queria por má expressão minha, e com tua ajuda eu ter conseguido 95% do que eu queria, reverti à minha primeira pergunta. Valeu.

Comment: Para deixar o `ylim` igual para todos os 8 plots, você pode definir `ylim = range(df)` and quando for plotar: `plot(..., ylim = ylim)`

Answer (score 4):

Para mim, a questão dos labels dos eixos é mais fácil de resolver utilizando o pacote `ggplot2` para fazer o gráfico. Para isto, é necessário primeiro preparar os teus dados de modo que eles fiquem em três colunas:

- `sinal`, com os valores de cada sinal, um após o outro
- `tempo`, com os valores temporais para cada sinal, o que implica que esta coluna terá n valores, mas apenas n/2 distintos, pois é necessário que o mesmo tempo ocorra para cada sinal
- `grupo`, que vai identificar se a observação referente a cada valor de `sinal` pertence ao grupo `v1` ou `v2`

Assumindo que os dados já foram gerados de acordo com a pergunta, o código abaixo faz isto que listei acima, colocando os resultados em um data frame chamado `dados`:

```
sinal <- c(v1, v2)
tempo <- rep(time_series_total, 2)
grupo <- rep(c("v1", "v2"), each=length(v1))

dados <- data.frame(sinal, tempo, grupo)
```

A seguir, basta usar os pacotes `ggplot2` e `scales` para gerar o gráfico desejado:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
ggplot(dados, aes(x=tempo, y=sinal, colour=grupo)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_datetime(labels=date_format("%B/%Y")) +
  labs(x="Data", y="Sinal", colour="Grupo")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Recomendo ver o help da função `scale_x_datetime` caso deseje alterar os intervalos entre os labels ou seu formato.

Comment: Valeu, Marcus. Tenho na verdade 8 vetores, registrados em 11060 horas. Ainda assim vc acha mais interessante criar uma data.frame com 11060x8 linhas? Vou tentar aqui e vejo o que faço. Além disso, acho que perguntei sobre a maneira de plotar, pois por enquanto quero fazer oito gráficos. O melhor jeito de fazer isso é no for mesmo?

Comment: Sim, acho mais interessante criar um data frame com 11060*8 linhas. Isto vai facilitar muito o teu trabalho. Sobre os gráficos diferentes, dá pra fazer com um `for` ou, se for do teu agrado, adicionar o comando `+ facet_wrap(~ grupo)` ao código que passei acima. Veja o resultado obtido e avalie se ele serve para o teu caso.

Comment: Modifiquei um tantão a minha pergunta, mas vou testar este facet_wrap.

Comment: Fazer este tipo de edição grande na pergunta, que altera completamente o sentido original dela, não é recomendado aqui no SO ([veja o porquê neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1115/ser%c3%a1-que-esta-%c3%a9-uma-pergunta-camale%c3%a3o)). Eu sugiro que esta edição seja desfeita e, dado que as duas respostas presente no momento deste comentário responderam a pergunta original, [alguma delas seja votada e aceita](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta). Crie uma nova pergunta com a sua dúvida atual.

Comment: Obrigado, Marcus. Na verdade, a resposta do william está mais próximo do que gostaria. Estou só confirmando isso. Talvez eu incluindo o for no código esteja tudo resolvido.